# Do Oculary beams in Skyrim only have two positions that don't work?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to focus the Oculary in Skyrim  on an XBOX 360.  I have every type of flame and frost spell, can hit the crystal in alternate shots or together - but no matter what I try, what combination of spells, order, where I shoot from - the beams go up in a narrow 'v'(the original position)  and down in a wide 'V', stopping in the same two positions each time. Neither formation has the beams cross where the mirrors can stop, and the beams always stop on the edge between the sliding rings the mirrors are on. ( in the original position, one of the beams is above the rings, not even ON a mirror ring at all.)

I have tried going back to an earlier save, but I had such a bitch of a time killing that automaton ( I suck at shooting stuff) that I really don't want to go back to any saves before that. No matter what i do, I can't get this to work.

Since I KNOW the Staff of Magnus is at Labrynthian, can I just go get it? Or do I need to finish this quest to make the next one work?  Can I get out of this dang room without having to go all the way back through the dwarven ruins? That took hours.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the game/console?

Comment: I played around with the positions of the mirrors and the heat/cold of the beams and eventually it just worked. Sometimes it would appear they reach locations they're not supposed to be in, but alternate between playing around with the mirrors or the beams till it works. Are you using Frostbite/Flames or stronger ones? You should use the weaker ones

Comment: The lowest ranked frost/fire spell worked for me, but it took a fair amount of trial and error. There is no way to enter Labyrinthian without the Torq of Labyrnthian I don't believe, unless there are pickable locks hidden somewhere, so you will  need to trigger the quest. I remember standing directly underneath the heat/cold mirrors and using the very basic spells to move them around

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Using just frost spell, make sure that one of the beams are on the top tier, one of the beams on the middle tier, and one of the beams on the bottom tier. Use only one type of spell. If the correct position is not found, you will reach a point where the frost spell won't do anything. If that happens, start using flame spell and go backwards. Remember we are only concerned about the height of each beam. One needs to be on top, one in the middle and one on the bottom.

Step 2: Once that happens. Keep pushing one of the buttons until the mirror is in position to reflect the beam, repeat with two other buttons.